# Satellite network hardware

Tags: network-core, architecture

I'm having some problems with the selection of components for the construction of a satellite network. For communication with satellite, I want to use DS-CDM 760 modem from Comtech. But there is a need to link it to the internal network on the Ethernet channel to connect with my WiMAX network. I need some additional hardware or can I connect directly to the server?

---

I have a mobile communications system with WiMAX network. The system is installed with the server on the basis of the vehicle Ford Transit. I would like to relate it to the satellite network using PESA antenna and Comtech modem. The server is running on Windows Server 2012. And yes, if I connect it through a switch to the server it will provide me with the necessary data rate? I need to use the full potential of the modem without losing speed.

[image]

---

I'm sorry if the question seems stupid, but I'm not faced with similar earlier. :)

Comment: You didn't provide enough information to answer your question. The DS-CDM 760 has a couple of 10/100/100 ethernet ports, and an SPF port if you need a fiber connection, which can be connected to an ethernet network. If you have ethernet switches, you can connect it to your network. You may need to put it on a separate subnet and use a router to connect the network from the device to the rest of the network. You should edit your question to add a network diagram.

Comment: Edit your question to add the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [data sheet for the DS-CDM 760](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjflsPN76fMAhXHsYMKHXnGDe0QFggdMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.comtechefdata.com%2Ffiles%2Fdatasheets%2Fds-cdm760.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGJJkH597oMS4AJ5ieA0pys8RwNQQ&sig2=8EDPHIXcZzcztt9_98HuKg), the data rate tops out at 314 Mbps. The ethernet ports on it support 1000 Mbps. To use the full capacity of the device, you need 1 Gbps in the network path (switch, server, etc.).

I don't see a problem, but I don't have all the information since I have no details on your network to which you wish to connect this. If the device is going to give you a new network, you will need to route between this new network and your existing network. Depending on how your network is laid out, you may be able to connect it directly to your router, or you could connect it to a layer-2 switch VLAN which runs to your router, or you could use a layer-3 switch to route it.

This is really all we can give you without more detail, and designing your network is not really what we do here.

Comment: I would like to insert it into an existing network. Here's a quick outline of what I want to implement to cover the necessary areas.

https://goo.gl/Onzh8U

Comment: See, that doesn't really give us the detail we need. What switches routers, servers, etc., and where in the network you want to connect this. If you can connect it to a 1 Gbps ethernet connection, and maintain 1 Gbps from it to the endpoint (server?), you will be able to get full use of the bandwidth.